# Concatenation in writeln?

Tags: concatenation, d

I am new to D and I am just trying things out. A book I am using gave me an example of a generic Binary Search method. I then wanted to make my own main method to print out the results just for fun. I come from Java where String Concatenation is simply done using the + operator.

But when I try that in D, it says that the two types (String and bool in this case) are incompatible. I tried to use the << operation instead as I've seen in C++ but then it told me that it wasn't an integral. How do I concatenate then?

```
import std.stdio, std.array;

void main() {
    bool b = binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 6);
    writeln("6 is in array: " + b);
    b = binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 5);
    writeln("5 i sin the array: "  + b);

}

bool binarySearch(T)(T[] input, T value) {
    while(!input.empty) {
        auto i = input.length / 2;
        auto mid = input[i];
        if(mid > value) input = input[0 .. i];
        else if (mid < value) input = input[i + 1 .. $];
        else return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest for writeln is to just separate it with commas.

```
writeln("6 is in array: ", b);
```

Each argument is automatically converted to string and outputted. writeln can take any number of arguments.

In general though, string concat in D is done with the `~` operator: `string a = b ~ c`; Both b and c have to be of type string.

To convert to string, you can do:

```
import std.conv;
int a = 10;
string s = to!string(a); // s == "10"
bool c = false;
string s2 = to!string(c); // s2 == "false"
```

std.conv.to can also convert to and from other types, e.g. to!int("12") == 12.

Thus, `string s = to!string(a) ~ " cool " ~ to!string(c);` will work there.

Comment: Hmm, it's probably because I am so new to D, but it looks kind of complicated to do something so simple given how a language like Java or C# handles the Class Casts itself.

Comment: It is possible to make a user defined type that can concatenate anything, but the builtin arrays don't do automatic conversion to make sure things are more explicit.

BTW there's a big gotcha though: in D, "hello" ~ 10 will actually compile, and you won't get "hello10" - you'll actually get "hello\n". The reason is that you can append other strings or you can append individal elements, in this case, chars. In the C tradition, ints can be converted to chars automatically. It assumes they are an ascii value. So watch out for that. to!string does the right thing though.

Comment: @Vipar There is a text() function in std.conv that can be used in place of the to!string function. e.g. string s = text(10) ~ text(20.3) ~ text('c') ~ text(true);

Comment: or for that matter, string s = text(10, 20.3, '3', true); i'm pretty sure works too